# vuejs: best practices with vuex when you call multiple actions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, electron

I am working on a project in which I am using vue js 2 and electron ,
to manage the state I use vuex  , I have at least 20 actions to call

```
 methods: {
        ...mapActions('Store1', ['FETCH_AB',...]),
        ...mapActions('Store2', ['FETCH_DS',...]),
        ...mapActions('Store3', ['FETCH_SD']),
        ...mapActions('Store4', ['FETCH_XD']),
        ...mapActions('Store5', ['FETCH_SD']),
        ...mapActions('Store6', ['FETCH_AZ'])
}
```

I use ...mapActions in my file vue
and to call it :

```
async mounted(){
  this.FETCH_AZ()
  this.FETCH_DS()
  ....
}
```

I created an method mounted
but i don't know if it's the best way to use vuex when you have enough actions to call
and there are actions that need getter or data from  actions
i mean by example :

```
const actions = {
 async FETCH_AZ(){
    const valueM8 = vm.$store.getters['Store1/GET_AB']
   ....
 }
}
```

i.e. an action can use the result of another action to do other operations

Comment: This is more of a theoretical issue than a practical example to work on